# MVP and non user interaction

Tags: android, architecture, mvp

I have an app designed using MVP pattern. But sometimes I'm not sure that all of our implementations stick to the MVP best practices. Although it's not always possible to work by the book I'm trying to figure out where should be the logic that deals with non user interactions.

For example:

I have to detect the offset of vertically scrolling RecyclerView. When scrolling reaches 20% of the content height (roughly) I should show a pop up. Now, my logic would be (pseudocode)

```
1. Presenter sets View.setVerticalOffsetTriggeringLimit(1000 pixels)
2. View triggers view event and call Presenter.offsetForPopUpReached()
3. Presenter triggers View.showPopUp()
4. pop up is shown
```

Pros and Cons? Is there a way to do it better while still have testable code? Is the System itself a "user" that should use presenter as a middle layer?

Answer (score 0):

All UI logic belong to View. Presenter has to have only interaction logic between Model and View. The point is, that View may differ - it can either be a UI, or, some module, sending commmands via sockets. The point is, that in both cases 'presentation logic' - as View interact with data remains the same, thus has to be moved into Presenter. Popups , margins, etc, is a View implementation details.
Handy practice- create Presenter as singleton and inject it by DI into Activity, which, in turn, implements View and connect it to that View. 
You can rid of Model by sending events from Presenter via EventBus (sticky events). If you do so, event will be waiting until Activity receive it (metigate Activity lifecycle). I encountered that approach little while ago.

Comment: Well, I can argue on that. Having the Presenter that updates the view after a button is pressed is no different than scrolling 1000 pixels and triggering an event. The models stay separated from the view anyway. It's all about testing the use case and having an Actor that is not necessarily a human but part of the UI should be treated equally. This kind of events aren't just UI stuff but an entire event chain that might (or might not) interact also with models.

Comment: Yes, I think, you right here. Try using 'mediator' here - interface, abstracting scrolling event and its implementatioin with RecyclerView, which is passed intoView. It can be replaced with mock for testing.